# Does PyPDF2 work with PDFs in landscape mode?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pypdf

I was a writing a program that should extract text from a PDF using PyPDF2, and when I ran the program, it worked with a document that was written in portrait mode and printed out text. However the second document was written in landscape mode, and when it was run through the program, it did not print out any text. Below is what my code currently looks like.

```
text = ""
pdf = PdfFileReader('TEST.pdf', 'rb')
for i in range(pdf.getNumPages())
    text += pdf.getPage(i).extractText()
print(text)
```

What I'm wondering is basically can PyPDF2 read documents if they are in landscape mode, or does their orientation matter when extracting text? For additional details on the documents, the font used in the successful document was written with "Grotesque Sans Serif" font (i.e. Helvetica), and the unsuccessful document was written in "Slab Serifs" font (i.e. Rockwell).

Below are what the PDFs look like. The first was the successful document, the second is the unsuccessful document: [image][image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My previous statement about PyPDF2 not working with PDF versions 1.4 was incorrect. I believe now the reason that the PDF did not work is because it was a bad PDF for whatever reason.

Comment: @KJ So are you saying that it is the program I've written fault, or is there something else? And when you refer to samples, are you referring to the samples I provided or something else? I'm just a little confused on what you could be stating is the issue with why PyPDF2 is not currently working with the below PDF that I provided. Thank you.

Comment: Okay, so you're saying that the PDFs that I uploaded, the bottom one doesn't work because it's just a flat out bad PDF. I think that makes sense. I was looking at different techniques, and I found one where it would basically convert each of the PDF pages to an image, and then use a different OCR to convert it all into a text file. Do you have any other recommendations for how I could read the bottom PDF? Also, for the purpose of uploading the images, I just used the snipping tool to show an example of what the program is reading.

Comment: @kJ Okay, I think I understand better now. So basically just be cautious of the results because they may not always be accurate. Another question I now have is do you think the bottom PDF failed because it is at a slight angle?

Comment: @kj okay I understand now! The main end goal of the program is actually to just compare the first four letters in the containers column with a set of pre-determined container codes. But I understand what you are saying with using a dictionary in order to ensure accuracy